# Why does molar conductivity depend on the volume of the solution?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, conductivity

I have been searching the answer to this question everywhere and (almost) the only answer I get is to formula based:
‘Since molar conductivity = k / M = k/1/V for one mole = kV

Therefore molar conductivity increases with decrease in concentration.’

A few rare answers explained the physical reasons citing decrease in attractive forces, etc.

My question is:
Conductance of an electrolyte is directly proportional to Area and inversely proportional to Length.
G = kA/l

The Molar Conductivity of an electrolyte on the other hand is dependant on the product of A and l = V
^m= kV

Why is it so despite both being quantities of almost the same type?

What I gathered after researching for quite a few hours is that due to decrease in the attractive forces between the molecules/ions of the electrolyte (and other reasons), Molar Conductivity does not follow the ‘rule’ of Conductance and has its own ‘rule’ in which it is directly proportional to the volume.

That is to say, the formula for Molar Conductivity cannot be derived from that of Conductance. They both have to be derived separately.

Of course I never saw anything suggesting that the second one is derived from the first but it wasn’t stated explicitly that that isn’t the case either. My textbook gave the formulas and definitions of the two in consecutive sections without addressing the contradiction in formulas.

How correct is my understanding?

Edit: On M.Farooq’s request,

Conductance = Degree to which an electrolyte conducts electricity. Inverse of resistance.

Conductivity = Conductance of unit volume of electrolyte.

Molar Conductivity = Conducting power of all ions produced by one gram mole of an electrolyte in a given solution.

Comment: Could you show where does it say that molar conductivity increases with the volume of the solution? I mean share the image of the book which says so.

Comment: Also write the definitions of conductivity, conductance, and molar conductivity in the edited question. This will help you sort out the issue. **Normal* conductivity is not a standard term. Clarify what do you mean by **normal**?

Comment: @M.Farooq Sorry. I should have said dependant on volume. I realised just now that since k also changes when V term changes (or Concentration changes). Does the point about it being independent of the Conductance equation still stand?

Comment: @M.Farooq I meant ‘Normal’ as in simply Conductance (=kA/l) since there are many conductances. I’ll edit the question to make it less confusing.

Comment: Molar conductivity for strong electrolytes increases due to increase in mobility of ions (as molecular interaction decreases on dilution). For weak electrolytes, it increases as number of ions increases (dissociation of electrolyte increases). For sparingly soluble salts, like AgCl, it remains essentially same with dilution. You can read about [Kohlrausch's Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohlrausch%27s_Law).

Comment: You are confusing V (the volume of the solution) and $V_m$ (the molar volume). They are very different properties. One is an extensive property dependent on the dimensions of the sample. The other does not depend on the volume (unless you are not scaling all extensive properties by the same factor).

Comment: @BuckThorn And the volume in the present case is not ‘Volume’? It’s ‘molar volume’?

Comment: Yes, when you divide the volume by the "amount of substance in moles" then you obtain the molar volume of the substance. Let's say you scale the solution by a factor x so that the volume becomes xV. But you also increased the amount of substance by factor x, so that it becomes xn. Then the molar volume of the scaled solution is xV/(xn) = V/n which is the same as the molar volume of the original solution.

Comment: When you computed the volume of solution for one mole you implicitly computed the "molar volume", an intensive property. It depends on the volume to the extent that you compute it as V/n, but it is "scale-invariant" (intensive) for simple thermodynamic systems.

Answer (score 1):

Let us clarify a couple of terminologies. You wrote the conceptual definitions. Now look up the mathematical definitions as well.

1. Conductance is the reciprocal of resistance of (a solution in your case). It is dependent on the solution concentration, distance between the electrodes, and area of the electrodes. The key point which you should recognize is that by area, we imply the volume enclosed by the electrodes.
2. In order to include all these variables into one quantity, one defines conductivity. Look up the mathematical definition in your textbook not on Wikipedia. Wiki has a horrible confusing discussion for a beginner.

Conductivity is still concentration dependent, because you will have to quote the concentration of the solution whose conductivity is being quoted. This quantity is independent of the cell dimensions. So no involvement of the volume here.

3. Here comes the surprise. If you divide conductivity by molar concentration, we get molar conductivity. *It should be independent of concentration. Turns out by experiment that it is not.* It depends on the concentration. For strong electrolytes, there is linear dependence and for weak electrolytes it is another non-linear dependence on concentrations of the electrolyte.
4. Kohlrausch found out >100 years ago, that molar conductivity at infinite dilution (a hypothetical calculated quantity) is independent of solution concentration.

In short, **molar conductivity does not depend on the volume of the solution.**

If this is still not clear, please share the page of the textbook which which specifically tells you that molar conductivity is volume dependent.

So if I assume, 1 take 1L of 0.01 M NaCl solution I will have a different molar conductivity and if I take 500 mL of 0.01 M NaCl solution, I will have a different molar conductivity...this is not true at all.